# Resource name cannot be used more than once

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, embedded-resource, visual-studio-2019

I have recently upgraded to VS 2019. Now, when I attempt to build, I receive the error:

> Resource name '.Resources.resources' cannot be used more than
>   once.

There is no page name or anything, and I have completely exhausted all that Google has to offer.

[image: Error Output]
Can someone help please?

Even I tried to troubleshoot the issue and below are the list of things which I have already tried.

1. To fix the issue, browsed to [obj > Debug] and [obj > release] and deleted any files which referenced the word resources.
2. I thought application using same resource name, as it is already defined.
   So tried to rename(Uniquely name resources) it, but didn't find any duplicate resource name.
3. Also tried below trick, but asusual nothing happened
   Build --> Clean
   Exit Visual Studio
   Re-open solution
   Build --> Build
4. Also found one solution by googling i.e: "On solution explorer click on "View All File",there under Frm1 there we will see 2 resource file like Frm1.resources and Frm1.resources1",so I need to delete second one. but in my case I didn't find any of this.

Comment: to be clear, you upgraded from Visual Studio 2010 to 2019 in one go, is that right? (I'm implying that because you tagged VB.NET 2010 originally). What version of .NET does the application target? The error looks like you have tried to add the same resource more than once...but obviously we can't see your code or project files etc so it's really quite difficult to know what could have happened.

Comment: A .resources file is generated from a .resx file, so you'd have to look at them to find the underlying cause.  You'd better also look at those 28 warnings.  What 1554 messages could try to say is hard to guess.

Comment: Instead of selectively deleting files in the bin and obj folders, delete the entire folder using File Explorer.  VS will recreate them.

Comment: Already tried by deleting bin and obj folder but nothing happened. @TnTinMn

Comment: Target framework is still same.@ADyson

Comment: Ok. But what _is_ the target framework? And you didn't answer my other question, and you haven't provide any extra info about your code or project....so not sure what further help we can give you. We don't ask these questions for fun...we need answers to them in order to help you.

Comment: @ADyson Target Framework is 4.0, and it is a big project can you please more specific what code do I need to show here.. it is a windows base application developed in VB.net, we are also using some third party libraries like DevExpress Winforms and ComponentOne FlexiGird.. and mentioned error is coming while trying to build and re-build the project for whole project not any specific form name. Basically in error window I can only see mentioned error and in file column file name is 'vbc'. which already mentioned in screenshot.

Comment: if you double-click those errors does it take you to any specific place? The obvious things to show us might be the place where you declare/configure those resources, and/or where you try to use them.

Comment: @ADyson When I am double click on these errors it wont take to me any form/page.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the resource file on solution explorer and change the 'Build Action' to "Compile" (it worked in my project)